# Track the historic of a time series for a market sentiment trading strategy. Error: argument of type 'numpy.bool_' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance, trading

[Problem visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQtfk.png) Hello!

I'm developing a market sentiment trading strategy for my Investment class. Basically, the strategy currently consists of selling the market index in Zone 1 and 3 and buying (holding) the market index on Zones 2 and 4. The zones are divided based on three lines : Upper (avg + std deviation), Lower (avg - std deviation) and Avg of a previous calculated Market Sentiment indicator.

What I want to do is to enhance the program by buying the market index  once you enter Zone 4 and exiting the market only once you hit Zone 1 and vice-versa. Zone 2 and 3, therefore, have their results based on the where the trend is coming from (if it entered through zone 1 or through zone 4).

How can I possibly do this?

Thanks for your help!

```py
 for i in range(data.shape[0]) :


        Zone_1 = data.loc[i,"Market Sentiment"] > data.loc[i,'Upper Bound']
        Zone_2 = data.loc[i,"Market Sentiment"] > data.loc[i,'Average Sentiment'] and data.loc[i,"Market Sentiment"] <= data.loc[i,'Upper Bound']
        Zone_3 = data.loc[i,"Market Sentiment"] > data.loc[i,'Lower Bound'] and data.loc[i,"Market Sentiment"] <= data.loc[i,'Average Sentiment']
        Zone_4 = data.loc[i,"Market Sentiment"] <= data.loc[i,'Lower Bound']

        if Zone_1:
            tracker = "n"
            list1.append(data.loc[i,'risk free rate']) 

        elif Zone_2 and data.loc[i-1,"Market Sentiment"] in Zone_1:
            tracker = 'down'
            list1.append(data.loc[i,'risk free rate']) 
        elif Zone_2 and data.loc[i-1,"Market Sentiment"] in Zone_2:
            if data.loc[i-1,'tracker'] == 'down':
                list1.append(data.loc[i,'HS300 Index Return'])
            else:
                list1.append(data.loc[i,'risk free rate'])

        elif Zone_2 and data.loc[i-1,'Market Sentiment'] in Zone_3:
            tracker = 'up'
            list1.append(data.loc[i,'HS300 Index Return'])

        elif Zone_3 and data.loc[i-1,'Market Sentiment'] in Zone_2:
            tracker = 'down'
            list1.append(data.loc[i,"risk free rate"])

        elif Zone_3 and data.loc[i-1,'Market Sentiment'] in Zone_3:
            if data.loc[i-1,'tracker'] == 'down':
                list1.append(data.loc[i,'risk free rate'])
            else:
                list1.append(data.loc[i,'HS300 Index Return'])
            list1.append(data.loc[i,'HS300 Index Return'])

        elif Zone_3 and data.loc[i-1,'Market Sentiment'] in Zone_4:
            tracker = 'up'
            list1.append(data.loc[i,'HS300 Index Return'])

        elif Zone_4:
            list1.append(data.loc[i,"HS300 Index Return"]) 

    data['Strategy Return'] = list1
    data['Tracker'] = tracker
    pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.4f}'.format
    return data
```